# Interface 'HTMLIonIconElement' cannot simultaneously extend types 'IonIc on' and 'HTMLStencilElement'

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, angular13

I have just upgraded my angular ionic app to use angular v13 from angular 12 by running `ng update`. The update was successful but now I am unable to run the app with below errors

```typescript
[ng] Error: node_modules/ionicons/dist/types/components.d.ts:66:15 - error TS2320: Interface 'HTMLIonIconElement' cannot simultaneously extend types 'IonIc
on' and 'HTMLStencilElement'.
[ng]   Named property 'ariaHidden' of types 'IonIcon' and 'HTMLStencilElement' are not identical.
[ng]
[ng] 66     interface HTMLIonIconElement extends Components.IonIcon, HTMLStencilElement {
[ng]                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[ng]
[ng]
[ng] Error: node_modules/ionicons/dist/types/components.d.ts:66:15 - error TS2320: Interface 'HTMLIonIconElement' cannot simultaneously extend types 'IonIc
on' and 'HTMLStencilElement'.
[ng]   Named property 'ariaLabel' of types 'IonIcon' and 'HTMLStencilElement' are not identical.
[ng]
[ng] 66     interface HTMLIonIconElement extends Components.IonIcon, HTMLStencilElement {
[ng]                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[ng]
[ng]
[ng] Error: node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:4632:101 - error TS2344: Type 'HTMLElementTagNameMap[K]' does not satisfy the constraint 'Element'.
[ng]   Type 'HTMLElement | HTMLMetaElement | HTMLAnchorElement | HTMLAreaElement | HTMLAudioElement | ... 151 more ... | HTMLMarqueeElement' is not assigna
ble to type 'Element'.
[ng]     Type 'HTMLIonIconElement' is not assignable to type 'Element'.
[ng]       Property 'ariaHidden' is optional in type 'HTMLIonIconElement' but required in type 'Element'.
[ng]
[ng] 4632     getElementsByTagName<K extends keyof HTMLElementTagNameMap>(qualifiedName: K): HTMLCollectionOf<HTMLElementTagNameMap[K]>;
[ng]                                                                                                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[ng]
[ng]
[ng] Error: node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:4953:101 - error TS2344: Type 'HTMLElementTagNameMap[K]' does not satisfy the constraint 'Element'.
[ng]   Type 'HTMLElement | HTMLMetaElement | HTMLAnchorElement | HTMLAreaElement | HTMLAudioElement | ... 151 more ... | HTMLMarqueeElement' is not assigna
ble to type 'Element'.
[ng]
[ng] 4953     getElementsByTagName<K extends keyof HTMLElementTagNameMap>(qualifiedName: K): HTMLCollectionOf<HTMLElementTagNameMap[K]>;
[ng]
```

The problem is that all the files being complained about are in the node_modules directory. How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 9):

For me I just added `"skipLibCheck": true,` in tsconfig.json, see code below:

[image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This worked but why?

Comment: Thanks! That solved the problem.

Ideally, it is better to upgrade Ionic libs, but this solution works well as a short-term fix.

The details about this flag can be found here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#skipLibCheck

Answer (score 2):

It seems that `ng update` updated the typescript version to 4.4, but ionic ion-icon seems to be incompatible with this version of typescript.

The current fix I used was to revert back to typescript version 4.3.5

How to perform this downgrade :

**update your package.json** ->
replace : `"typescript": "~4.4.4"`
with `"typescript": "~4.3.5"`

**then run** -> `npm install`

If someone has more information about the root cause of this incompatibility and an other way of solving this, I am very much interested since I very much would like to upgrade to typescript 4.4.

Comment: Tried this but I am unable to run `npm i` Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer typescript@"~4.4.3" from @angular-devkit/build-angular@13.0.2
npm WARN node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular.

Comment: I already had this too, can you instead try with :
`npm install --legacy-peer-deps`

Answer (score 0):

The following tsconfig.json configuration works for me.

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "es2020",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",

    "lib": ["es2018", "dom"]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true
  }
}
```

Comment: be sure update your @angular/cdk": "^13.3.9",  your current angular version should be there